# problem loading combobox with xml doc

Tags: actionscript-3, flexbuilder

The requirement is:
there is a XML doc i recived from HttpService tag in flex.I need to populate a combobox with the ids content in xml doc.
xml doc is:

```
   <head>
 <meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type"/>
 <title>JSP Page</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <h2>Directory Service WP</h2>
 <h3>Starting DS Service</h3>
 <hr/>
 SSL hostname verified.
 <hr/>
 Request sent.
 <hr/>
 <message>
   <params>
     <IncidendID>
       <ID>Incident-140c169f-1cd6-4ec5-a5d0-0aff303bbfec</ID>
    <ID>Incident-fff5ba34-6b42-4feb-859e-0bafbdf1c542</ID>
    <ID>Incident-87fcf355-4d00-4743-bc29-999aef8c8386</ID>
    <ID>Incident-c3f89a1b-7791-4405-a20f-f33239cb4773</ID>
    <ID>Incident-ac4a5fec-6414-444c-bad7-be43350d7d0a</ID>
    <ID>Incident-87b71101-ace3-425e-806c-ba4fc6271571</ID>
    <ID>Incident-19865863-6882-4669-bbd7-263c32ea01f8</ID>
    <ID>Incident-c08be10a-9b99-4819-9132-1f18a271d278</ID>
    <ID>Incident-913112c8-414b-41f8-ba1d-fadb7ed97e80</ID>
    <ID>Incident-5c3ba408-0138-49b7-9fac-410aa709baa4</ID>
    <ID>Incident-40fa5264-ae1a-42fd-8cdf-20f69c5eaa80</ID>
    <ID>Incident-85333369-195c-4359-af65-045d072be377</ID>
    <ID>Incident-fcfd1385-ac64-40b2-8d26-66e6a23d07e3</ID>
    <ID>Incident-d255929d-0bcf-4a1c-9abf-7c2e4804fa74</ID>
    <ID>Incident-de2f591e-982a-434d-ab60-8170bacdddbd</ID>
    <ID>Incident-f33de939-a025-4033-9486-90f2916021f1</ID>
    <ID>Incident-53b5822a-7663-4c94-8014-ace38b634ad3</ID>
    <ID>Incident-8a3d83fe-5e01-401d-8a2a-e1f495ef7fbd</ID>
    <ID>Incident-1ef1694a-ed7a-4ac8-a422-55ca806a1169</ID>
    <ID>Incident-9003c195-ad83-4cc7-9f43-dab11b360d8a</ID>
    <ID>Incident-767e2afb-d17e-455c-a3b6-a83ec547bd67</ID>
    <ID>Incident-515a009b-edaa-402c-a920-0f968e7c9099</ID>
    <ID>Incident-a01e1da2-a59c-4b18-a6c1-a8e82cdc7296</ID>
    <ID>Incident-3e2f8957-ee24-4b4f-b76e-6039936c5e31</ID>
    <ID>Incident-7f1c3b5a-fa7d-4a74-8deb-a5affb043691</ID>
    </IncidendID>
  </params>
 </message>
</body>
```

and the flex code is:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml"
            xmlns:maps="com.google.maps.*"
            viewSourceURL="srcview/index.html">

<mx:Script source="Assets/getInZip.as" />               

<mx:states>
    <mx:State name="loading">
        <mx:AddChild relativeTo="{this}" position="lastChild">
            <mx:ProgressBar id="loadProgress" width="100%" />
        </mx:AddChild>          
    </mx:State>
    <mx:State name="error">
        <mx:AddChild relativeTo="{this}" position="lastChild">
            <mx:Label id="errorLabel" />
        </mx:AddChild>
    </mx:State>
</mx:states>
<mx:HTTPService id="httpA" result="ResultFn(event)" url="http://localhost:8084/GetIncidentId/getIncidents.jsp" resultFormat="xml"/> 
<mx:Button id="bttnHttpA" label="Get Data" click="httpA.send()"/>
<mx:ComboBox id="IncCbx"></mx:ComboBox>
    <mx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
                all imports
       private function ResultFn(event:ResultEvent):void
        {

                Alert.show("Hey... event form HTTP 1"); 
                //IncIdArr = XMLListCollection(event.result);
                //Alert.show("IncIdArr" + IncIdArr);
                var retxml:XML = XML(event.result);   
                Alert.show("list: " + retxml.children());     

                //Alert.show("Result:" + retxml);   
                IncCbx.dataProvider = retxml.children();  
             }
```

need help with this.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should isolate the ID elements if that's what you're trying to display. Try this:

```
private function ResultFn(event:ResultEvent):void {
     var retxml:XML = MXL(event.result);
     IncCbx.dataProvider = new XMLListCollection(retxml.body.message.params.IncidendID.ID);
}
```